# Dynamic port forward TCP traffic over reverse SSH tunnel

Tags: go, reverse-proxy, socks, ssh-tunnel

I have an SSH tunnel which dial into the server endpoint and starts up a remote listener on a port `1080`. My goal is to dynamically forward any TCP traffic from that port to the client side of the tunnel. While I am able to accept TCP stream I am not able to find a way to `Dial` out on the client side of the SSH tunnel. It looks like the `dialer` I am passing is the `serverConn` server SSH end of the tunnel. And when I am attempting to `remote, err := dialer.DialTCP("tcp4", local.RemoteAddr().(*net.TCPAddr), addr)` I get the traffic dial on the remote end. I want to find a way to dial out at the client side over a reverse tunnel.

I am not looking to forward specific ports to a specific destination on local, but looking to do more dynamic port forwarding similar to `ssh -D` option. I am managing destination of TCP traffic myself, this is not a concern.

I have tried to create `ssh.NewClient` from the passed `serverConn` but it needs to perform an SSH handshake, and Iam only receiving raw TCP on the port `1080` so it's not a valid SSH client. Thanks.

```
func main(){

    type Dialer interface {
       DialTCP(net string, laddr, raddr *net.TCPAddr) (net.Conn, error)
    }

    // SSH server connection
    sshConfig := &ssh.ClientConfig{
         User: "tester",
         Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
         ssh.PublicKeys(signer),
         },
         HostKeyCallback: ssh.InsecureIgnoreHostKey(),
    }
    // Connect to SSH remote server using serverEndpoint (port 22)
    serverConn, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", serverEndpoint.String(), sshConfig)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(fmt.Printf("Dial INTO remote server error: %s", err))
    }

    // Listen on remote server port (port 1080)
    listener, err := serverConn.Listen("tcp", 
                     remoteEndpoint.String())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(fmt.Printf("Listen open port ON remote server error: %s", err))
    }
    defer listener.Close()

    acceptSLoop(listener, serverConn)
}

func acceptSLoop(listener net.Listener, sshClient *ssh.Client) {

    fmt.Printf("Listener: %s\n", listener.Addr().String())
    defer listener.Close()
    for {
        clientConn, err := listener.Accept()
        fmt.Printf("local addr %s\n", clientConn.LocalAddr())
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("New connection found on %s\n", listener.Addr().String())
        listenSConnection(clientConn, sshClient, config)
     }
 }

func listenSConnection(SClientConn net.Conn, sshClient 
  *ssh.Client) {
     // In a regular SSH I need to do
     // sshConn, chans, reqs, err := 
     ssh.NewServerConn(SClientConn, // config will be 
         passed in ..)
     //
     // But since it's TCP handoff I am passing socket data 
        directly
     handleSConn(SClientConn, sshClient)
 }

func handleSConn(local net.Conn, dialer Dialer) {
       defer local.Close()

       // Both of those establish socket from "remote" ssh side (Server) not "local" ssh side (client)
       remote, err := dialer.DialTCP("tcp4", local.RemoteAddr().(*net.TCPAddr), addr)
       //remote, err := net.Dial("tcp4", addr.String())

       // transfer bytes from local SOCKS to remote desired endpoint over SSH
       transfer(local, remote)
}

// in - local SOCKS conn, out - remote desired endpoint
func transfer(in, out net.Conn) {
     //.... working
}
```

Comment: Your `defer listener.Close()` statement before you start the goroutine is going to close your listener, possibly before your goroutine even executes anything. You only need the deferred call that you have in the `acceptSLoop` function.

Comment: Actually the problem with the posted code is not the defer, but rather that nothing is preventing main() from exiting immediately, taking all running goroutines with it.

Comment: UPDATE: I don't seem to be able to modify the post. @MadWombat this is a mistake on my part, the code i have has 2 port listeners: one blocking, the other has `go` routine so main effectively is blocked in a listen loop. I dropped the idea of dialing out in SSH `dialer` and just did a `remote, err := net.Dial("tcp4", addr.String())` and it seems to work on the right side. I don't know if this is fragile or how it is supposed to work with the tunnel.